# Letting users send HTML emails without risking being tagged as spam

Tags: html, django, email

I maintain a Python/Django app. My client wants to have a refer-a-friend program, where users could send a nicely designed (and therefore HTML-based) email to their friends to use our product, and get some free product from us.

This puts me in a dilemma. One option is to let the clients email their friends by giving them a `mailto:` link. But that way I won't be able to include the pretty HTML email we got designed. Another option is to have our system send that HTML email for them, with a form that'll let them put in the email addresses. (Our system sends email via SendGrid.)

But, what I'm concerned about is having our account marked as spam. I heard that if even a few people do "Report Spam" on messages that you send, then mail providers are more likely to tag your emails as spam. This is a website that sends transactional emails to paying customers every day; **if some of our emails will end up in spam folders, it would be a disaster and a huge risk for the business.**

I'm worried that if some users will send these refer-a-friend emails to many people (including people they don't really know) in order to get more promotions, then some of these people would hit "Report spam" and we'll have the aforementioned problem.

I figure I could add some limitations, like letting a person send to just 3 people, but they'd be easy for someone to bypass. (I am considering not only users but also attackers, our ability to send email reliably is that critical.)

And that's my dilemma. How can I let my users send HTML emails without risking being marked as spam?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the best HTML, deliver the most ethical and honest content and follow all anti-spam tips but you can't avoid a user to report your email as SPAM.

Your main concern shouldn't be a manual spam report. You should indeed avoid that the Internet Providers considers your email as SPAM **automatically** without the user intervention.

To do that, you've already started right: using SendGrid or other serious SMTP providers to deliver your emails. They are experts and keep your emails away from SPAM filters.

If you can spend an extra bucket: keep a private IP address just for yourself (they provide this service).

And to test if your are sending a "polite" email, use [Mail Tester](http://www.mail-tester.com/). It's free and they test several aspects of your email content and network delivery.

My premisses are:

1) if email is well formed, it will not be included on a spam list automatically.

2) give a clear opportunity to the receiver to opt-out; People used to report spam if they receive 2 or 3 emails with the same matter without their consent.

So my solution would be:

1) Write the HTML template and use the Mail Tester to test if it's well formed and follow all anti-spam rules;

2) On your template, add a clear message and a link to a form where he/she could unsubscribe your referee program; Add this email on a do-not-bother list.

3) If another user try to add a email on this list, inform that those person don't want to receive this kind of email.

Comment: Great tips but doesn't answer the question really. Sorry.

Comment: Indeed I didn't conclude well my answer! I add a better conclusion.